# Asking a misleading question again with rephrased text?

Tags: support, questions

I just asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467955/get-the-base-folder-of-a-third-party-click-once-application) about Click-Once application. Unfortunately it seems that I did not explain clear enough that I am not the developer of that application and that the question is from the point of view of a user of that application.

So I got some comments and an answer that did not match my original intent. Stupid me.

I rephrased the text of my question to make it more clear. However the thread is a bit messy now containing comments and an answer to the wrong question.

Should I try to clear the thread in some way or may I start a new thread asking the rephrased question from the scratch?

Comment: Iff you decide to re-ask, making sure you actually ask the question you wanted, first take some time to polish your old question, making it clearly ask that other question you didn't actually want to ask instead. And I'm not yet convinced re-asking would be right.

Comment: Since it's already answered, I would suggest to make the answer valid first to value the answerer's effort by editing your question. Now, the real question, if you think you can't revise the question to the one that you wanted to ask, then I think you can ask a new question while referencing and explaining that the previous question is not a duplicate. Make sure to follow Deduplicator advice too.